# Error when opening a (silently) saved file c#

Tags: c#, richtextbox, streamwriter

I have been making a text editor in c#, and recently added the functionality to silently save the file (without SaveFileDialog).  The file appears to save properly, however, when trying to open the file, i get the error `System.ArgumentException - File format is not valid`.  It opens fine if the file has not been saved silently.

The code:

The save method:

```
    public void save(RichTextBoxPrintCtrl.RichTextBoxPrintCtrl rtbIn, string fileNameIn)
    {
        string fileName = "";
        if (getFileFromMap(fileNameIn) != "")
        {
            // The file already exists in the Map so save it
            fileName = getFileFromMap(fileNameIn);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName);
            writer.Write(rtbIn.Text);
            writer.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            // The file does not exist in the Map so
            // Send it to SaveAs with the rtb and the initial fileName passed in
            saveAs(rtbIn, fileNameIn);
        }

    }
```

SaveAs:

```
    public string saveAs(RichTextBoxPrintCtrl.RichTextBoxPrintCtrl rtbIn, string fileName)
    {
        saveDialog.FileName = fileName;
        saveDialog.Title = "Save As";

        if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (saveDialog.FileName.Length > 0)
            {
                if (saveDialog.FileName.EndsWith(".rtf"))
                {
                    rtbIn.SaveFile(saveDialog.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
                }
                else
                {
                    rtbIn.SaveFile(saveDialog.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
                }
                addFileToMap(fileName, saveDialog.FileName);
                return Path.GetFileName(saveDialog.FileName);
            }
            else { return ""; }
        }
        else { return ""; }
    }
```

and Open:

```
    public string open(RichTextBoxPrintCtrl.RichTextBoxPrintCtrl rtbIn)
    {
        if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (openDialog.FileName.Length > 0)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(openDialog.FileName);

                if (fileName.EndsWith(".rtf"))
                {
                    rtbIn.LoadFile(openDialog.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
                }
                else
                {
                    rtbIn.LoadFile(openDialog.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
                }
                addFileToMap(openDialog.FileName, openDialog.FileName);
                return fileName;
            }
            else { return ""; }
        }
        else { return ""; }
    }
```

Other information:

- The filenames are stored in a Dictionary because the editor has tabs.
- RichTextBoxPrintCtrl is a custom RichTextBox that supports printing, it doesn't change anything relating to opening
- The methods above are in a separate class which is why they require the richtextbox to be passed in.

If you need any other code, just let me know.
Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:**
Fixed, couldn't use StreamWriter.

Comment: As an aside, now would be a good time to start following .NET naming conventions, using `using` statements, and learning about methods like `File.WriteAllText`.

Comment: @JonSkeet you mean with capitals to start the names? I write like that because I'm used to Java naming... I'll try to start following the conventions :)

Comment: Yes, exactly. I know there's a temptation to stick to your previous conventions, but it's really worth making an effort to follow the conventions of the language you're actually using.

Comment: Can't seem to find anything wrong with your code... at which line does the exception does occur in the `open` method?

Comment: Is your silent save running on its own thread or on the UI thread?

Comment: @Roman its occurring on `rtbIn.LoadFile(openDialog.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);`

Comment: @InBetween it is running on the UI thread i guess, i didn't explicitly make one

Comment: But how is the silent save initiated? With a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` or some other way?

Comment: @InBetween the silent save is the save method. It's activated by pressing save, if there is a save already in the dictionary. Like Word, the first time you save a dialog shows up, and every time after it just saves it. That's what I'm trying to do

Comment: oh ok, I thought you were implementing an autosave feature like MS word for instance, the will make periodic back up saves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the issue seems to be that you are not saving the file in the same way.

When you perform a `saveAs`, you are calling `rtb.SaveFile`. In your silent `save` you are directly trying to save the `rtb.Text` to the file but that is probably not the correct format `rtb.OpenFile` is expecting.

I am no expert whatsoever in `RichTextBox` but spotting the difference when on method works and another similar one doesn't normally helps.

To expand a little more, `Text` returns only the plain text (no content formatting information). Your method `save` is saving as plain text any file, even if its a .rtf. Your `Open` method on the other hand will try to open an `.rtf` file as a formatted text, this can be causing the issues you are having.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that I couldn't use StreamWriter